# Powershell Search for TCP connections by port

Tags: powershell, tcp

I wasn't able to find any posted code that would do something like a `netstat` in PowerShell and then search for established TCP connections by port.

I wrote the following function which works and was hoping for some feedback. Is there a simpler way? My company is still on Windows 7 so I can't use `Get-NetTcpConnection`.

```
<# Get-ESTConnectionByPort
Usage: Pass the port number to the function and it will return a boolian
value of true or false it will also echo an "Connected" or "Not Connected"
output to the console.
Get-ESTConnectionbyPort -Port "443"
#>
function Get-ESTConnectionByPort {
    Param($Port)

    $NetworkProperties = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties()

    $TcpConnections = $NetworkProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections()

    $TCPOut = $TcpConnections | Select-Object State, RemoteEndPoint

    $TCPTable = @($TCPOut.where({
        $_.RemoteEndPoint -match '.:' + $Port + '\z' -and
        $_.State -eq "Established"
    }))

    $Value = (-not $TCPTable)

    if (-not $Value) {
        Write-Host "Connected"
        $script:TCPConnected = $true
    } else {
        Write-Host "Not Connected"
        $script:TCPConnected = $false
    }

    $script:TCPConnected
}
```

Comment: are you at least upgraded to ps5.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does the job in a slightly different way. it uses the `.Where()` and  `.ForEach()` array methods for a slight speed-up. if you run PS2 or PS3, you will need to replace those with their pipeline versions [`Where-Object` & `ForEach-Object`].

it allows multiple port numbers & multiple states to be chosen, then generates a `[PSCusomtObject]`, sorts by the port, and finally outputs the objects. there are no other outputs.

```
function Get-TcpConnectionInfo
    {
    <#
    Comment Based Help goes here
    #>

    [CmdletBinding ()]
    Param (
        [Parameter (
            Position = 0
            )]
            [int[]]
            $Port = 443,

        [Parameter (
            Position = 1
            )]
            [ValidateSet (
                'Established',
                'CloseWait',
                'TimeWait'
                )]
            [string[]]
            $State = 'Established'
        )

    begin {}

    process
        {
        $State = @($State).ForEach({$_.ToLower()})

        @([System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties().
            GetActiveTcpConnections()).
            Where({
                # include only foreign RemoteEndPoint items
                $_.LocalEndPoint.Address -ne $_.RemoteEndPoint.Address -and
                $_.State.ToString().ToLower() -in $State -and
                $_.RemoteEndPoint.Port -in $Port
                }).
            ForEach({
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    State = $_.State
                    RemoteEndPoint = $_.RemoteEndPoint
                    }
                }) |
            Sort-Object {$_.RemoteEndPoint.Port}
        }

    end {}

    } # end >> function Get-TcpConnectionInfo
```

with the following call ...

```
Get-TcpConnectionInfo -Port 443, 993 -State closewait, established
```

... it returns this ...

```
      State RemoteEndPoint    
      ----- --------------    
  CloseWait 13.33.115.238:443 
Established 151.101.65.69:443 
Established 198.252.206.25:443
Established 23.194.113.80:443 
Established 40.97.120.242:993 
Established 173.194.70.108:993
Established 173.194.70.108:993
Established 40.97.120.242:993
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel.

There is a cmdlet specifically for this, unless you are on an OS or lower PowerShell version that does not have it.

```
# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Test-NetConnection).Parameters
Get-help -Name Test-NetConnection -Examples

<#
    Example 3: Test TCP connectivity and display detailed results

    PS C:\> Test-NetConnection -Port 80 -InformationLevel "Detailed"
    ComputerName            : internetbeacon.msedge.net
    RemoteAddress           : 2a01:111:2003::52
    RemotePort              : 80
    NameResolutionResults   : 2a01:111:2003::52
                            13.107.4.52
    MatchingIPsecRules      : Ipsec/Domain-TrafficFromInternet-v6
    NetworkIsolationContext : Internet
    IsAdmin                 : False
    InterfaceAlias          : Ethernet
    SourceAddress           : 2001:4898:d8:33:81e8:7b49:8bf5:8710
    NetRoute (NextHop)      : fe80::200:5eff:fe00:203
    TcpTestSucceeded        : True

    This command tests TCP connectivity to a default server and sets the InformationLevel parameter to Detailed.
#>

Get-help -Name Test-NetConnection -Full
Get-help -Name Test-NetConnection -Online
```

There has been posted code for this use case for a while now.

[Test-NetworkPort 1.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Test-NetworkPort/1.0) 
A script to test if a TCP or UDP port is open.

Comment: the OP is stuck with win7 & the `Test-NetConnection` does not exist on win7ps5.1 ... [*sigh ...*] from what i can tell, you need at least win8+.

Comment: Hey Lee, Roger that, which is why I pointer to that gallery script that does work on lower versions. There are older builds for that same script that the OP could download and tweak as well. Also, like your helpful answer, the are tons of these all over the web, even one the combine Test-Connection with System.Net.Socket.TCPClient, which was a cute way to do it. Here: http://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-test-port-connectivity/1214

Comment: ooo! kool ... thanks for the links! i'm off to do some reading ... [*grin*]